# Using a backreference as key in a hashmap within a regex-substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

I am learning the Perl language and I stumbled upon the following question:
Is it possible to use a backreference as a key in a substitution argument, e.g. something like:

```
$hm{"Cat"} = "Dog";
while(<>){
s/Cat/$hm{\1}/
print;
}
```

That is, I want to tell Perl to look up a key which is contained in a capture argument.

I know that this is a silly example. But I am just curious on the question as to whether it is possible to use such a key-lookup with a backreference in a substitution.

Comment: Try it out then :).  The correct syntax: `perl -wE'$_=shift//q(eko); %h = (k => 7); s/(k)/$h{$1}/; say'` (This is a command-line program, a "one-liner" -- copy the code and paste it on the command-line and hit Enter).  Note, youo need to "capture" the pattern `(k)`. Then use `$1` (not `\1`) -- in other words, don't use a backrefernce but rather use capture

Answer (score 2):

Use `$1` instead.

While backrefs like `\1` work in the substition part of a regex, it only works in string context. The `$hm{KEY}` is accesses an item in a hash. The KEY part can be a bareword or an expression. In an expression, `\1` would be a “reference to a literal scalar with value `1`” which would stringify as `SCALAR(0x55776153ecb0)`, not a back-reference as in a string. Instead, we can access the value of captures in the regex with variables like `$1`.

But that requires us to capture a part of the regex. I would write it as:

```perl
s/(Cat)/$hm{$1}/;
```

As a rule of thumb, only use backrefs like `\1` *within* a regex pattern. Everywhere else use capture variables like `$1`. If you `use warnings`, Perl will also tell you that `\1 better written as $1`, though it wouldn't have detected the particular issue in your case as the `\1` was still valid syntax, albeit with different meaning.

Comment: "_The KEY part can be a bareword or an expression._"  -- for it to be treated as an expression (in the replacement part of the regex) we'd need `/e` modifier, I think.  Otherwise it is treated as a literal to compute the hash value with.  (With `/e` it says `Can't use \1 to mean $1 in expression` while without it it says `Use of uninitialized value $h{"SCALAR(0x1546e58)"} in substitution iterator`).  (May be a good idea to mention `/e` in this context anyway?)

Comment: (The messages are when I use `$h{\1}`, like in a one-liner in my comment under the question)

Comment: @zdim I don't think `/e` is relevant here – this particular code will behave exactly the same regardless. The extra “Can't use \1 to mean $1” extra warning is arguably a false positive since it is valid syntax here!

Comment: "_this particular code will behave exactly the same regardless_"  -- right, agree (except for that warning when `\1` is used under `/e`).  I think that the extra warnings are Perl's pre-emptive action toward typical errors etc.  Anyway, this was just a side comment to a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at really old code, you'll see people using the `\1` form on the replacement side of the substitution. Sometimes you'll see it in really new code; it's a Perl 4 thing that still works, but [Perl 5 added a warning](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Perl/perl5/a0d0e21ea6ea90a22318550944fe6cb09ae10cda/pod/perldiag.pod).  If you have warnings turned on, perl will tell you that (although I don't know when this warning started:

```
$ perl5.36.0 -wpe 's/cat(dog)/\1/'
\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1.
```

With diagnostics you get even more information about the warning:

```
$ perl5.36.0 -Mdiagnostics -wpe 's/cat(dog)/\1/'
\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W syntax) Outside of patterns, backreferences live on as variables.
    The use of backslashes is grandfathered on the right-hand side of a
    substitution, but stylistically it's better to use the variable form
    because other Perl programmers will expect it, and it works better if
    there are more than 9 backreferences.
```

There are many other warnings that Perl uses to show you better ways to do things.

A level above that is [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic), which is an opinionated set of policies about what some people find to be good style. It's not a terrible place to start before you develop your own ideas about what works for you or your team.

Answer (score 1):

It has been explained that one wants to use a capture for that, not a backreference, like

```
perl -wE'$_=shift//q(hal); %h = (a => 7); s/(a)/$h{$1}/; say'
```

What I'd like to add is a note about what if there isn't in fact a key for that capture?

We often capture complex patterns, not simple literals, and it can happen that our anticipated keys don't cover every case that may come up.  A way to check for that involves the [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) `/e`, which makes the replacement part be evaluated as code, and its return is then substituted into the string

```
perl -wE'$_=shift//q(hal); %h = (a => 7); s{(h)}{$h{$1} // "default"}e; say'
```

Now if the pattern is matched and captured but isn't a key (`h`)  then the string `default` is substituted.  An often sensible choice for default is the capture itself (if not a key put it back).

The replaccement part must now be syntactically correct *code*, so no bare literals, etc.